# Capture thermal camera stream using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I have the following simple script to capture and show stream from a thermal camera:

```
import cv2


camera_index = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_index)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS, 0.5)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_WB_TEMPERATURE, 3500)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Thermal camera', frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am not able to get correct images using this script, the image I am getting in return looks like this:

[image]

I believe I am doing something wrong here with colors and formats as I expect a black-and-white thermal image from this.

Edit:

Camera: Optis Xi 400
Frame shape:  (290, 382, 3)
Frame type:  uint8

Comment: that looks like a pixel contains four bytes.

Comment: You could mention your camera make/model and operating system. You could print `frame.shape` and `frame.dtype` immediately after `cap.read()`.

Comment: Are you using a process interface? Are you configuring the camera's setting or are they preset?

Comment: @OriYarden the camera is just plugged in through USB, no other settings are interfaced.

Comment: Are you sure this camera is supported? It seems to be ignoring your 640x480 size setting and giving you 290x382 in colour. Have you tried inspecting the first few bytes with `print(frame.ravel()[:20])`

Comment: Do some trial-and-error with the `cv2.CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS` and `cv2.CAP_PROP_WB_TEMPERATUR` parameters (if they're even actually setting anything) and input a range of values. You can also try Bonsai's (animal tracking software) camera capture to see if it get any sort of image. Otherwise, try using the software packages recommended on the website. It doesn't look like no image, but it's not really showing anything in the image you provided.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I think it is just the size of the image, so it is not able to go up to 640x480. frame.ravel()[:20] returns `[  0 255  26   0 255  35   0 255  27   0 255   4   0 232   0  26 255  75
   0 255]`

Comment: In [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66909370/thermal-image-processing) I encountered about thermal cameras, the camera output was 16 bits per pixel. The camera output is never colored, and the automatic conversion to BGR applied by OpenCV messes with the video. Try adding `video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, 0)`, and also try `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FORMAT, -1)`. Read the frame as `764x290` and then use `frame.view(np.uint16)`. There are cases when data is signed `frame.view(np.int16)`. There are cases when data is big endian, and bytes should be swapped.